# Populate Userform textbox based on cell selected by Combox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, textbox, userform

In my excel document I have the following information in two columns:

```
US Dollar (USD)                     1
British Pound (GBP)                 0.63
Guatemalan Quetzal (GTQ)            0.13
Honduras Lempira (HNL)              0.046
Other                               Please give factor
Other                               Please give factor
Other                               Please give factor
Other                               Please give factor
```

I have a combobox that is populated by the first column:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
CurrencyList.List = Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A23:A30").Value
End Sub|
```

I want to automatically populate a textbox with the currency conversion in the next column, so when you select the currency in the combobox it automatically populates the textbox so you can either leave it as suggested or change it if you wish. I am on a mac with excel 2011. All the solutions I have come across seem to work for windows and I get errors saying the methods I have called do not exist.

Comment: What specifically have you tried?  This should be a matter of using `VLookup` via `Application.VLookup` or `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` once the selection is changed on the Combo Box.  I don't think being on a Mac affects either of those functions.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using an offset or do I have to populate the combobox in a different way by naming the range in the sheet? Ill add an edit to my question showing what went wrong, may take a while to find out what I tried as I didn't note it down! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. It populates the forms combobox with your values(which you had already) and the Vlookup finds the currency associated with the values in the combobox. Double check that your ComboBox and TextBox Name property matches your code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A23:A30").Value

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    TextBox1.Text = Application.VLookup(ComboBox1.Value, Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A23:B27"), 2, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi this works when I select the currency (i.e. the relevent conversion rate pops up) but when I try and add the value to another sheet I get a mismatch error, any idea what may be going wrong? thanks for your help

Comment: If I understand you want to take the textbox value and place it in another sheet? I dont know how you want to execute this event (when the textbox values is changed, a button, etc). But the code would be similar to my answer above.  `Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Text

End Sub`